# opencv- vehicle tracking using optical flow

Tags: opencv

I have implemented optical flow to track vehicles on road and it turned out to be very slow.

my code uses the functions:

- cvGoodFeaturesToTrack
- cvFindCornerSubPix
- cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK

How do I make this tracking fast and efficient?

My code is:

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


const int MAX_CORNERS = 500;

int main()
{
CvCapture* capture=cvCreateFileCapture("E:\cam1.avi");
IplImage* img_A;// = cvLoadImage("image0.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
IplImage* img_B;// = cvLoadImage("image1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
img_A=cvQueryFrame(capture);

IplImage* imgA = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img_A), 8, 1 );
IplImage* imgB = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img_A), 8, 1 );
cvNamedWindow( "ImageA", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cvNamedWindow( "ImageB", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cvNamedWindow( "LKpyr_OpticalFlow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

while(1)
{
    int couter=0;
    for(int k=0;k<20;k++)
    {
        img_B=cvQueryFrame(capture);
    }


    //cvCvtColor(imgA,imgA,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    //cvCvtColor(imgB,imgB,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // Load two images and allocate other structures
    /*IplImage* imgA = cvLoadImage("image0.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    IplImage* imgB = cvLoadImage("image1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);*/

    CvSize img_sz = cvGetSize( img_A );
    int win_size = 10;



    IplImage* imgC = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img_A), 8, 1 );
    cvZero(imgC);
    // Get the features for tracking
    IplImage* eig_image = cvCreateImage( img_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
    IplImage* tmp_image = cvCreateImage( img_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );

    int corner_count = MAX_CORNERS;

    CvPoint2D32f* cornersA = new CvPoint2D32f[ MAX_CORNERS ];


    cvCvtColor(img_A,imgA,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cvCvtColor(img_B,imgB,CV_BGR2GRAY);


    cvGoodFeaturesToTrack( imgA, eig_image, tmp_image, cornersA, &corner_count ,0.05, 5.0, 0, 3, 0, 0.04 );

    cvFindCornerSubPix( imgA, cornersA, corner_count, cvSize( win_size, win_size ) ,cvSize( -1, -1 ), cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, 0.03 ) );

    // Call Lucas Kanade algorithm
    char features_found[ MAX_CORNERS ];
    float feature_errors[ MAX_CORNERS ];

    CvSize pyr_sz = cvSize( imgA->width+8, imgB->height/3 );

    IplImage* pyrA = cvCreateImage( pyr_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
    IplImage* pyrB = cvCreateImage( pyr_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );

    CvPoint2D32f* cornersB = new CvPoint2D32f[ MAX_CORNERS ];

    /*int jk=0;
    for(int i=0;i<imgA->width;i+=10)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<imgA->height;j+=10)
        {
            cornersA[jk].x=i;
            cornersA[jk].y=j;
            ++jk;
        }
    }
  */
    cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK( imgA, imgB, pyrA, pyrB, cornersA, cornersB, corner_count,
        cvSize( win_size, win_size ), 5, features_found, feature_errors,
         cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, 0.3 ), 0 );

    // Make an image of the results


    for( int i=0; i < corner_count; i++ ) 
    {
        if( features_found[i]==0|| feature_errors[i]>550 ) 
        {
            //printf("Error is %f/n",feature_errors[i]);
            continue;
        }
        //printf("Got it/n");
        CvPoint p0 = cvPoint( cvRound( cornersA[i].x ), cvRound( cornersA[i].y ) );
        CvPoint p1 = cvPoint( cvRound( cornersB[i].x ), cvRound( cornersB[i].y ) );
        cvLine( imgC, p0, p1, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 2 );
        cout<<p0.x<<" "<<p0.y<<endl;
    }




    cvShowImage( "LKpyr_OpticalFlow", imgC );
    cvShowImage( "ImageA", imgA );
    cvShowImage( "ImageB", imgB );
    //cvCopyImage(imgB,imgA);
    delete[] cornersA;
    delete[] cornersB;
    cvWaitKey(33);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better move it to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I might be going a bit over the line here but I would suggest you to check out [`OpenTLD`](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/). OpenTLD (aka Predator) is one of the most efficient tracking algorithm. Zdenek Kalal has implemented OpenTLD in MATLAB. George Nebehay has made a very efficient [`C++ OpenCV port of OpenTLD`](https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD).

It's very easy to install and tracking is really efficient.

OpenTLD uses Median Flow Tracker to track and implements PN learning algorithm. In this [YouTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=1GhNXHCQGsM), Zdenek Kalal shows the use of OpenTLD.

If you just want to implement a Median Flow Tracker, follow this link https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD/tree/master/src/mftracker

If you want to use it in Python, I have made a [Median Flow Tracker](https://github.com/jayrambhia/MFTracker) and also made a [Python port of OpenTLD](http://github.com/jayrambhia/pyOpenTLD). But python port isn't much efficient.

Answer (score 5):

First of all to track a car you have to somehow detect it (using color segmentation/background subtraction for example). When car is detected you have to track it (track some points on it) using `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. I didn't find code that responces for car detection.

Take a look at [this](http://www.ces.clemson.edu/~stb/ece847/projects/VISION_BASED_VEHICLE_TRACKING.pdf) and [this](http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/iasted08amol.pdf) articles. Your idea should be the same.

Also your code is a bit wrong. For example why do you call `cvGoodFeaturesToTrack` in the main loop? You have to call it once - before loop to detect good features to track. But this will also detect non-cars.

Take a look at default OpenCV example: [OpenCV/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp?rev=4118).

Comment: i have already done bakground subtraction , detection
 i am only left with this tracking part  which is kind of very slow

Comment: @SumitKumarSaha this is slow because you call `cvGoodFeaturesToTrack` in loop instead of calling it before. See example.